# How to make JavaScript 'dataTable' reflect changing a cell's value on the resulting web page?

Tags: javascript, datatable, cell

From the Chrome JavaScript debugger this logic/code is working correctly, and drilling down on the table again for this cell shows it is now " ", as wanted, however this cell update is not shown on the web page? Please see image below.

However the table as shown on the page is not updated to reflect this change. I believe I am changing this value before the table is turned into HTML, but it appears that I am not. Any guidance would be great, I am not a web dev guy, just working on a problem.

```
       var maxRecs = maxTransactionCount;
            // Extract "mxr" max records for this transaction search, try to then remove from table.... 
            try {
                var table2 = table;

                var maxRecsTmp = table.fnGetData(0, 10);
                if (maxRecsTmp != null && maxRecsTmp !== "") {
                    maxRecs = maxRecsTmp;
                    var tset = table.fnSettings();
                    var oCol = tset.aoColumns[10];
                    var oDat = tset.aoData[0]._aData;
                    oCol.fnSetData(oDat, " ");
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                debugger;
            }
```

How Table is showing after setting 20004 to " " :

[image: How Table is showing after setting 20004 to " " :]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the [Datatables legacy API's](https://legacy.datatables.net/api) but I did not find one called `fnSetData`.  I did find one called `fnUpdate`.  Maybe that is what you need to use instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'fnUpdate' nor 'table.cell(row, 10).data(" ").draw();' work both return '.fnUpdate' and '.cell' is not a function.  Keep in mind the javascript above changes the cell's value, the webpage ignores this update.

Comment: Maybe you just need to draw the table with fnDraw.